# Insert rows of dates missing for every ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to insert rows when there are missing dates in every ID as suggested in the title, by using the date range as the MIN and MAX date.
Here is an example of the table that I have:

| device_id | date | speed | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-08 | 50 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-06-09 | 30 | 15 |
| 1 | 2021-06-12 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 2021-06-07 | 10 | 15 |
| 2 | 2021-06-10 | 60 | 5 |

And I want to insert rows so that information that is not available turns None or Null, like this:

| device_id | date | speed | height |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-07 | None | None |
| 1 | 2021-06-08 | 50 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-06-09 | 30 | 15 |
| 1 | 2021-06-10 | None | None |
| 1 | 2021-06-11 | None | None |
| 1 | 2021-06-12 | 20 | 20 |
| 2 | 2021-06-07 | 10 | 15 |
| 2 | 2021-06-08 | None | None |
| 2 | 2021-06-09 | None | None |
| 2 | 2021-06-10 | 60 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-06-11 | None | None |
| 2 | 2021-06-12 | None | None |

If you can see, the rows inserted are for every date missing in every "device_id", and columns "speed" and "height" enter as "None", so that I have information for every date in the range of dates used in the first table. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: `generate_series()` and a `LEFT JOIN`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

```
SELECT i.device_id
     , d.date
     , CASE WHEN t.date IS NULL THEN 'None' ELSE t.speed :: text END AS speed 
     , CASE WHEN t.date IS NULL THEN 'None' ELSE t.height :: text END AS height 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT generate_series(min(date), max(date), interval '1 day') AS date
       FROM your_table
     ) AS d
 CROSS JOIN
     ( SELECT DISTINCT device_id
         FROM your_table
     ) AS i
  LEFT JOIN your_table AS t
    ON t.date = d.date
   AND t.device_id = i.device_id
 ORDER BY i.device_id, d.date
```

Result :

```
device_id   date                    speed   height
1           2021-06-07 00:00:00+01  None    None
1           2021-06-08 00:00:00+01  50      10
1           2021-06-09 00:00:00+01  30      15
1           2021-06-10 00:00:00+01  None    None
1           2021-06-11 00:00:00+01  None    None
1           2021-06-12 00:00:00+01  20      20
2           2021-06-07 00:00:00+01  10      15
2           2021-06-08 00:00:00+01  None    None
2           2021-06-09 00:00:00+01  None    None
2           2021-06-10 00:00:00+01  60      5
2           2021-06-11 00:00:00+01  None    None
2           2021-06-12 00:00:00+01  None    None
```

see the demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b3ac9c47ba7f4301f1fb5792be9d3fce)

Comment: Thanks! it's a bit more compact than the other answer, but both are useful.

Comment: Yes both solutions are very similar for sure.  You can keep @Stephanov.sm's idea of COALESCE() instead of CASE WHEN NULL THEN ... ELSE ... END? My proposal defines dynamically the start and end dates to be considered.

Answer (score 2):

As @stickybit suggests, using step-by-step CTEs:

```sql
with dates("date") as 
(
  select generate_series('2021-06-07'::timestamp, '2021-06-12', interval '1 day')::date
),
device_ids(device_id) as 
(
  select distinct device_id from the_table
),
fulllist as 
(
  select * 
  from dates cross join device_ids
)
select device_id, "date", coalesce(speed::text,'None') speed, coalesce(height::text,'None') height 
from fulllist 
left join the_table using (device_id, "date")
order by device_id, "date";
```

I do not think however that `text` is a good choice for datatype of `speed` and `height` as well as the word 'None' for missing values. Simple

```sql
select device_id, "date", speed, height
```

yielding `null`s for missing values would be far more relevant.

Comment: Thank you! I understood very well your answer even though I'm a beginner in this area hahaha. A little question, why do you use "using" when you are doing the lef join?

Comment: This [using](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) is a shorthand and I hope better readable for `on the_table.device_id = fullist.device_id and the_table."date" = fullist."date"`. An extra benefit is that these two columns are not duplicated in the resultset.