# View to Insert Rows for Missing Dates for Each Employee ID

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, view

I need to display rows dynamically within a view on Azure SQL Database when there are missing Snapshot Dates dates for every Employee ID as suggested in the title, by using the [Snapshot Date] for each [Employee Number] as the MIN and MAX date. [Snapshot Date] is always the last day of the month.

The reason for doing this is that after several months of inactivity, an employee will drop out of various applications so their record goes "missing" from reporting. But we want to continue reporting on inactive / deleted employees for every snapshot period after the last date they were last seen in the system.

This is what my data currently looks like.

There are tons of columns after Employee Status, and I want to populate the data in these columns [Example Column] as nulls.

| Employee Number - Snapshot Year-Month | Snapshot Date | Employee Number | Employee Status | Example Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999999-2022-12 | 2022-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-11 | 2022-11-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-10 | 2022-10-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-09 | 2022-09-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-08 | 2022-08-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-07 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-06 | 2022-06-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-05 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-04 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |

What I want it to look like:

| Employee Number - Snapshot Year-Month | Snapshot Date | Employee Number | Employee Status | Example Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999999-2023-10 | 2023-10-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-09 | 2023-09-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-08 | 2023-08-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-07 | 2023-07-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-06 | 2023-06-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-05 | 2023-05-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-04 | 2023-04-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-03 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-02 | 2023-02-28 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2023-01 | 2023-01-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-12 | 2022-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-11 | 2022-11-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-10 | 2022-10-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-09 | 2022-09-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-08 | 2022-08-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-07 | 2022-07-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-06 | 2022-06-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-05 | 2022-05-31 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |
| 999999-2022-04 | 2022-04-30 00:00:00.0000000 | 999999 | Inactive | null |

A further complication is that some employees have Snapshot Dates going back as far as 2017-04. I want to only populate data going forward from the MIN Snapshot Date that exists for an Employee Number.

I am looking for a solution like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70393259/insert-rows-of-dates-missing-for-every-id?newreg=ddf9bd38c12545d28ef93cba3bd61d44]. However, I'm unable to use GENERATE_SERIES since my version of SQL server doesn't support it and I'm unable to upgrade.

Can anyone help?